# How can I compare content of two web pages?

Tags: node.js, web

I want to check the difference between content which was generated on the build server with current one.

How can I compare content of two web pages (by url) with help of Node.js or command line?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) :

```
request('your url 1', function (error1, response1, body1) {
    request('your url 2', function (error2, response2, body2) {
        // You can compare in here with body1 and body2
    });
});
```

Or with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) (with promise)

But you should create file js and run it.

Comment: Exactly what is needed!